# WPF Async Programming (Using Threads)

Tags: xml, vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I am pretty new to Asynchronous programming and still trying to learn it. I have an application which reads huge XML file (approx. 2GB) and then parse it in to tables. As XMLreader take lot of time, therefore I need Asynchronous methods. I created a  Button (OnClick Event) Async and used the Task/Await but it gives me an error (maybe I am not using it correctly). Then, after reading online, I wrote the following code (using Threads).

```
Private Sub Parse_Btn_2G_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Parse_Btn_2G.Click

        Dim count As ArrayList
        Dim action As Action
        Dim Thread As Thread = New Thread(Sub()
                                              count = CountXML()
                                              action = Sub()
                                                           Status_Txtbox.Text = count(0).ToString() + " Managed Objects in XML"
                                                       End Sub
                                              Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(action)
                                          End Sub)
        Thread.Start()
        Status_Txtbox.Text = "Processing File. Please Wait...."
    End Sub
```

CountXML is the method which is reading XML file and counting the Attributes. here is the code for counting attributes.

```
Private Function CountXML() As ArrayList

        Dim settings As New XmlReaderSettings
        settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore
        settings.Async = True
        Dim MONumbers As ArrayList = New ArrayList
        Dim ADCEcount As Integer = 0
        Dim BSCCount As Integer = 0
        Dim BCFCount As Integer = 0
        Dim TRXCount As Integer = 0

        Dim desiredvalue As Boolean = True

        Dim xReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(xml_txtbox_2G.Text, settings)
        Dim ns As XNamespace = XNamespace.Get("raml20.xsd")

        While xReader.Read()
            If xReader.Name <> "managedObject" Then
                xReader.ReadToFollowing("managedObject")
            End If
            If Not xReader.EOF Then
                Dim managedObject As XElement = XElement.ReadFrom(xReader)

                If CType(managedObject.Attribute("class"), String) = "ADCE" Then
                    ADCEcount = ADCEcount + 1
                End If

                If CType(managedObject.Attribute("class"), String) = "BSC" Then
                    BSCCount = BSCCount + 1
                End If

                If CType(managedObject.Attribute("class"), String) = "BCF" Then
                    BCFCount = BCFCount + 1
                End If

                If CType(managedObject.Attribute("class"), String) = "TRX" Then
                    TRXCount = TRXCount + 1
                End If
            End If  
        End While

        MONumbers.Add(ADCEcount)
        MONumbers.Add(BSCCount)
        MONumbers.Add(BCFCount)
        MONumbers.Add(TRXCount) 
        Return MONumbers
    End Function
```

The Function CountXML() works perfectly fine when I don't use threads or Await/Task code but as soon as I use threads, I get an error message

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access
>   this object because a different thread owns it.'

I think this is because xml_txtbox_2G.Text is a textbox control (having a xml file path) which is used by UI Thread already. Can someone please guide how to release it or use asynchronous method in reading the xml file. Thanks

Comment: You don't want to release the text box.  You do want to ensure that any updates to it happen from the UI thread.  There should be documentation on how to do this; I'd suggest starting with looking at `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: Also, let me suggest an alternative to your current approach: Only push `CountXML` off into another thread, then when it finishes, the code running on the UI thread receives the result and updates the text box directly.  Multi-threaded code is a lot easier to reason about (and write correctly) if it doesn't have any side effects.  You can do this with `Async / Await` and `Task.Run` if you prefer.

Comment: As an aside, I would strongly recommend against using `ArrayList` if you can avoid it.  The generic collections are almost always a better choice.

Comment: Looking at your code again, you are using a `Dispatch.Invoke` on the text box update, so I'm not sure why there's a problem with it.

Comment: Thanks Craig, i had to return multiple values (of different Managed Objects) from the function so for this reason I am using ArrayList. I tried Async & Await option but then it takes lot more time to complete. Application becomes responsive but then the process / thread / task because very slow to complete

Comment: I will try to use your suggested code below. Do you know if backgroundworker is a good option? I tried it too but seen no improvement in time of completion.

Comment: In my experience, it doesn't seem like `Async / Await` has a major impact on performance; I'm not sure why it's a problem in your case.  I wouldn't expect a significant difference from a background worker because I would expect `Task.Run` to be using that behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can cast your problem into `Async / Await` with relatively minor modifications.  I haven't tested the following code, but it's similar to material that I've written that works.

```
Private Async Sub Parse_Btn_2G_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Parse_Btn_2G.Click
    Status_Txtbox.Text = "Processing File. Please Wait...."
    Dim count = Await CountXML
    Status_Txtbox.Text = count(0).ToString() + " Managed Objects in XML"
End Sub

Private Async Function CountXML() As Task(Of ArrayList)
    Dim asTask = Task.Run(Function() CountXMLImpl)
    Return Await asTask
End Function

Private Function CountXMLImpl() As ArrayList
    'Current contents of CountXML.  You might name this and the async version differently if desired.
End Function
```

If you might want to cancel work in progress, you can provide a cancellation token to `Task.Run`.  In my experience, this only seems to have an effect on tasks that are queued waiting for a thread, but aren't actively processing.  I haven't looked into what I might need to do to force a running task to halt and cancel; perhaps the correct thing to do is to take a cancellation token as an argument to the underlying routine and periodically check whether the token has requested cancellation.

```
Private Async Function CountXML(ByVal cancellationSource as System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource)
    Dim asTask = Task.Run(Function() CountXMLImpl, cancellationSource.Token)
    Return Await asTask
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, i tried the above code and it works fine for XMLReader function but if i try to use it with another function (like  function with MS access update) then it takes lot more time. I am using DAO to update MS Access. Not sure if DAO should be used with Async or not ?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelAhmed If you can push it off to a worker thread, then there is still potential value in keeping a responsive UI while the work is proceeding, even if it takes a while.  Any operation that might take a while is suitable for `Async`; the only special cases are things that support it directly (thus that you can `Await` on directly) instead of needing to explicitly push them off onto a separate thread or task.

Comment: Thanks Craig, really appreciated, I have managed to create a thread and now I see that it is taking considerable amount of time. Issue with access still exists, irrespective if I use Async or Threading, both takes lot of time to update datatable to access. If I use synchronouse then it is very fast , (just the application hangs as expected)

Comment: is there a way to cancel the await/task with the click of a button ? I can do that in Thread easily with thread.abort option but is it possible to abort the task if required ?

Comment: @MuhammadAdeelAhmed You can provide a cancellation token to `Task.Run` and cancel the token.  In my experience, the task generated by `Task.Run` does not interactively check for cancellation, so canceling will only stop a task that's idle, waiting for an available thread.  For my application, I didn't feel that it was critical to be able to kill a task in progress (my individual tasks take less than a minute) so I didn't look into it further.  I'll edit the answer to add info on providing a cancellation token.